# How to rebind a repeater inside master page from a content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible to rebind a repeater (inside master page) from content page?
My pages are base on master and content pages and I have some links (anchors) for download files!

After click on those links page_load of content page fires, and will show download window. But we will never get page_Load of master page and in master page I have a summary for showing download counts.

How can I rebind that summary (inside master page) from content page before showing download window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty simple. You can 'find' the control from the content page.
Here's a sample where i'm binding to a GridView control.

Master:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridViewMaster" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

Content Page:

```
var gridView = (GridView) Master.FindControl("gridViewMaster");

gridView.DataSource = dt;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Just replace the grid view object and control id with your repeater...and bind it to whatever object you want.

Edit - Here's the code to find a server side div:

```
var divMaster = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("divMaster");
divMaster.InnerHtml = "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
```

Comment: Dear Ed B, really thanks. is it possible to do this job for a server-side div?

Comment: Yes, it works the same way. Just add the div to the master. Then find it on the content page. I've added the code to find the server-side div above

Comment: i test that, i tried this >  var SummaryContainer = Master.FindControl("SummaryContainer");
                            SummaryContainer.DataBind(); but that div never shows me new results and i should click on a button in page for getting results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You have access to the master page from your web form—using `this.Master`—which you'd then have to cast as the appropriate type.  From there you can access any public methods or properties you've defined.

Simple add a `ReBind` method there that does what you want, and you should be good to go.

**EDIT**

It would be something like:

`(this.Master as WhateverTypeYourRealMasterPageIs).ReBind();`

Comment: thanks for all answers / would you please show me some codes!

Comment: thanks for edit, WhateverTypeYourRealMasterPageIs -> how can i found that ? i tried (this.Master as MasterPage).ReBind(); but have error!

Comment: Go to the code behind of your master page.  You should be able to see the class name there.  That's the type of the master page class.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do so is for the user control to fire an event that the Master page subscribes to. Let me know if you need some sample code

Some sample code:

In your user control, add the following event:

> public event EventHandler RefreshRequested;

The user control will throw this event whenever it wants a refresh by calling the following method:

```
private void OnRefreshRequested()
{
    //make sure the event is being listened to. no point raising an event if no one cares!
    if (this.RefreshRequested != null)
    {
        this.RefreshRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now,  the master page will subscribe to the user control's event and acts accordingly. Subscribing to the event is just like subscribing to any other event (ie: Button_Click).

Let me know if this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the master page control to the children.  Make the control public with an accessor in the master page... such as:

```
public Repeater MasterpageRptr {get;set;}
```

Then on your child page, add the MasterType definition:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Content Page" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.master"%>
<%@ MasterType TypeName="MyMaster" %>

(where MyMaster is the master page class file)
```

Then you can call this in your child code-behide using the accessor.

.

.

Please vote if helpful.

Comment: thanks for help.is it possible do this job for a server-side div?